# Scalable webrtc implementation

Tags: webrtc

**PROBLEM:**

I am trying webrtc multi-videoconferencing by **"muaz khan"**, but it taking to much cpu usage as I connected to 10 peers. My CPU usage is nearly 200%. Also In case of broadcasting **"muaz khan"** scalable broadcasting is not that effective because it using concept of multilevel

***Question***

1) Can any one suggest something that will take down cpu usage down & scalable broadcasting.

2) Any other option to Media server technique.

3) Also can any one tell me any open source "Media server technique", I have tried kurento's but they don't have many-to-many in node & they are not free right??

4) kurento provide Android & IOS sdk? If not then please tell me any Client like kurento(open source) which provide Android & IOS sdk.

Comment: You can set constraints on the connection to limit bandwidth, resolution and frame rate. This can significantly lower CPU usage. If you use a custom or open source renderer, you can also limit the frame rate of the rendering to further decrease CPU usage. Other than that, you're pretty much limited to the hardware, there isn't much optimisation to do.

Comment: Agreed with @kevin. The only thing you can do is mixing all the streams in the media server, but that also takes its toll in resources. There are Android and iOS clients for Kurento, but they are not official.

Comment: @igracia can I do multiple broadcasting at same time using kurento application code. Can you help me about that.

Comment: @PratikDeshmukh What do you mean with multiple broadcasting? If you mean several 1:N pipelines, that is indeed possible.

Comment: @igracia I mean to say is suppose I am have 3 broadcaster and the want to broadcast to N people at same time(3 Broadcasting running in parallel) with kurentu application.

But because of this code I can't do it:

 if (presenter !== null) {
  stop(sessionId);
  return callback("Another user is currently acting as presenter. Try again later ...");
 }

Comment: @PratikDeshmukh The tutorial works like it's designed to work. If you want to do something different, then you'll have to modify it. Also, notice that there is only one presenter in that tutorial, so it's not as easy as removing that line of code and it'll work as you expect. Please notice also that I never said that the tutorial would allow you to do that out of the box, you'll need to do some modifications.

Comment: @igracia so you mean to say it possible right?
I have seen your post here as well [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kurento/yXnWUlJrnEM]

Comment: @PratikDeshmukh Yes, it is possible, but you'll have to modify the demo to support different sessions. This is not hard, and if you study the different tutorials, you'll get it very quickly.

Comment: @igracia Thanks for the help. I have implemented the multiple session code. But I have one last doubt can you help to understand the use of function **onIceCandidate(sessionId, _candidate)**  & **candidatesQueue** variable.